# Existence of uniformly bounded Darboux chart

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

In Donaldson's paper *Symplectic submanifolds and almost-complex geometry*, he mentioned that for each point $p$ in a compact almost-Kähler manifold $(V,\omega ,J)$, there exists a Darboux chart $\varphi_p\colon B^{2n} (1)\to V$ such that $\varphi_p (0)=p$ and the derivative of $\varphi_p$, measured with respect to the Levi-Civita connection and the Riemannian metric induced by $J$ and $\omega$, is bounded and the upper-bound is independent of the choice of the point $p$. Why is this the case? I don't know how to attack this.

Comment: Just a random thought - I haven't thought about symplectic geometry in a while: is it possible that charts on balls with fixed radius $\rho > 0$ are allowed? Otherwise it would seem a bit weird given that it could presumably be that $\mathrm{vol}(V) < \omega_{2n}$. If a radius $\rho \in (0,1)$ were admissible, then it seems you could do a covering argument and translate your charts, no?